# Why does this stop working once I introduce a parameter to the type? (scala)

Tags: scala

I'm working with this program

```scala
abstract class Foo[+T[_]] {}
case object Unit extends Foo
case class Cons[+T[_]](a: Foo[T], b: Foo[T]) extends Foo[T]
case class Strings[T[_]](x: T[String]) extends Foo[T]
def first[T[_]](v: Foo[T]): Option[Foo[T]] = v match {
  case Cons(a, b) => Some(a)
  case _ => None
}
```

and getting the error

```
constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type;
 found   : Cons[T]
 required: Foo[?T1] where type ?T1 <: T (this is a GADT skolem)
```

But if I get rid of the parameter for `T` it works just fine?

```scala
abstract class Foo[+T] {}
case object Unit extends Foo
case class Cons[+T](a: Foo[T], b: Foo[T]) extends Foo[T]
case class Val[T](x: T) extends Foo[T]
def first[T](v: Foo[T]): Option[Foo[T]] = v match {
  case Cons(a, b) => Some(a)
  case _ => None
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of covariance of `Foo` and `Cons`. If you remove `+`s everything will compile. In covariant case when you match `v` of type `Foo[T]` with pattern `Cons(a, b)` this `a` is not necessarily of type `Foo[T]` with the same `T`, `a` can be of any type `Foo[T']` with `T' >: T` (or `Foo[Any]`), which contradicts return type. With your custom `unapply` you remove this uncertainty in type.

Comment: This makes sense except that this works with all the variance when `T` is not a constructor type. Note the code that starts with `abstract class Foo[+T] {}` compiles just fine with all the `+`s and no custom `unapply`. If `T` is invariant in `Foo` then I can't have my `case object`.

Comment: @StevenNoble Looks like a bug https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8563 The code when `T` is not a constructor type shouldn't compile either.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to be able to solve this by supplying my own `Cons.unapply`. I'm unclear why I need to write my own.

```scala
object Cons {
  def unapply[T[_]](v: Foo[T]): Option[(Foo[T], Foo[T])] = {
    if(v.isInstanceOf[Cons[T]]) {
      v.asInstanceOf[Cons[T]] match {
        case Cons(a,b) => Some((a,b))
        case _ => None
      }
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
}
```